# replacement has length zero on ave function in R

Tags: r

im working on changing the name of several pictures, actually the the length(filename)=length(name) and both are aprox 1.4million entries, the name_idx have about 350,000 entries

```
filename <- c("1.jpg", "2.jpg" "3.jpg", ...., )
name <- c("a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "b",....,)
name_idx <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", ..., )
```

i want to create another list which will contain the new name of the picture, the first entry would be a.1.jpg and the 5th would be a.2.jpg, the 4th would be c.2.jpg and so on

someone in stackoverflow giveme this solution

```
paste0(name, ".", ave(name, name, FUN = seq_along), ".jpg")
```

but im getting this error

```
Error in x[...] <- m : replacement has length zero
```

i was hoping you can helpme to know why is this and how to solve it?

Comment: It seems to work without any problems here. Does `name` contain NA values?

Comment: not exactly NA but words with ñ or several spaces, those affect?

Comment: Possibly. Special characters may be a nuisance. I haven't got much experience with them. But if that is the case, a quick test using only `ave(name, name, FUN = seq_along)` for the appropriate elements would let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally done it in python, whit the glob and the os libraries =3